# White labeling silverstripe project

Tags: silverstripe

I m fairly new in Silverstripe. We've a project in silverstripe and we are asked to do white labelling.
That means there will be different URLs that will be accessing same codebase with different design, logos, members, etc.

For Example, We have three clients

Client: ABC

```
URL: http://www.abcclient.com/admin
URL: http://www.abcclient.com/
```

Client: XYZ

```
URL: http://www.xyzclient.com/admin
URL: http://www.xyzclient.com/
```

Client: PQR

```
URL: http://www.pqrclient.com/admin
URL: http://www.pqrclient.com/
```

etc

**Requirement**

- Each client have their own admin url and client url.
- Each domain should point to same folder in the server.
- Each client should have their own members (in Security module in admin)
- Each client should have their own CMS design, Client design, logos

**What I have done so far?**

- I have created new Page "Clients" in CMS, that adds each clients,
  along with their details.
- I have extended Members so that while adding/editing members,the custom dropdown will appear that will list all available clients. And from there we can select the Client which the member belong to.

**Problem**

1. Can we whitelabel Silverstripe? If yes how?
2. When admin is accessed from certain domain, they will only see/filter/add/edit Files, Members related to them.

I m not asking for Code, but an idea will do a great help.

**UPDATE**
The project doesn't have frontend based on Silverstripe so need to whitelabel CMS only.

Thanks

Comment: you should have a look at: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we whitelabel Silverstripe? If yes how?

Yes Silverstripe is BSD license so there is no need to mention silverstripe at all!

For starters add this to the config.yml

```
LeftAndMain:
  application_name: 'My Application'
  application_link: 'http://www.example.com/'
  extra_requirements_css:
    - mysite/css/branding.css
```

with this in `mysite/css/branding.css`

```
.ss-loading-screen {
    background: #fff;
}
.ss-loading-screen .loading-logo {
    background: transparent url('../images/my-logo-loading.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.cms-logo a {
    background: transparent url('../images/my-logo-small.png') no-repeat left center;
}
```

> When admin is accessed from certain domain, they will only see/filter/add/edit Files, Members related to them.

I've not used it, but the [Subsites Module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites) is the recommended approach for this.  from the module readme.md...

"The subsites module provides a convenient way of running multiple websites from a single installation of SilverStripe, sharing users, content, and assets between them - the sites will be managed from a single CMS.

A useful way to think of its use is where you have a business with a global headquarters and four branches in various countries. The subsites module allows the five offices to use a single SilverStripe installation, and have information from the headquarters flow down into the branches. The branches can hold information that is individual and the website templates can also be different."

As well as the module there is also [user help for subsites](https://userhelp.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/optional_features/working_with_multiple_sites/).

Specifically where there is different content per site and you wish to restrict these objects based on the subsite... the documentation covers that [here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites#enable-subsite-support-on-dataobjects)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In my case, CMS will be different from different clients, and when they log in, they will only see/add/edit/delete Files, Members, etc related to them only. Is this possible with subsite module?? Also note that I only need white labeling for CMS. We don't have frontend so don't need anything for frontend

Comment: Yes it's possible, I've added a link to that (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites#enable-subsite-support-on-dataobjects) note it is just one page down the module you are being recommended to use, please read a little more about it if you have more doubts

Comment: Hi thanks again, do we have to edit all DataObjects including Custom and builtin (Security, Files, etc) ?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites/tree/1.2/code/extensions for the object automatically added... if the object you want isn't in that list then yes you need to follow the above link (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites#enable-subsite-support-on-dataobjects) or create an extension (if a core object)

Comment: yeah went through it, filtering records by Subsite worked for custom modules, but didn't work for Security Module. I created Extension for`SecurityAdmin` and override `getEditForm` method, but didn't work

Comment: I'm confident that this is the solution, however I'm going to let you decide on whether this answer is acceptable or to wait for others.  I would advise to split the questions in future as I'm 100% certain I've answered one of your two questions here and the second you've stated "you are not after code, but the idea" and I think I've certainly given the right idea.  Be Well :)